# Formatting column name in dual table

Tags: sql

How to add spaces or special characters to column name when using SELECT * FROM dual;

For example, if I want to print "Hello World" as the column name, how should I use this with dual table as the following is not working.

```
SELECT 'HELLO WORLD' FROM dual;
```

This displays result as:

```
'HELLOWORLD'
------------
HELLO WORLD
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 'HELLO WORLD' as HELLOWORLD FROM dual;
```

or

```
SELECT 'HELLO WORLD' as "HELLO WORLD" FROM dual;
```

See **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/16915/1)**

Comment: The second one works! Thanks a lot. (Though I am trying to export this result to an Excel sheet and it fails there because of some illegal hostname error. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

You may also try brackets:

```
SELECT 'HELLO WORLD' as [HELLO WORLD] FROM dual;
```